# Get screen size in x86 BIOS bootloader?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bios

Im using x86 assembly nasm to build a bootable iso, but I'm wondering how to get the bios screen size in pixels in order to draw a box the size of the screen

SI = screen width

DI = screen height

boot.asm:

```
bits 16
org 100h

start:
    int 0x15
    mov ah,0
    mov al,13h
    int 10h

    mov cx,0
    mov dx,0
    mov si,1920
    mov di,1080
    mov al,0x1
    call draw_box

draw_box:
    push si
    .xdraw:
        push di
        .ydraw:
            pusha
            mov bh,0
            add cx,si
            add dx,di
            mov ah,0xC
            int 0x10
            popa
        sub di,1
        jnz .ydraw
        pop di
    sub si,1
    jnz .xdraw
    pop si
    ret
```

Comment: The BIOS boots you in 80x25 text mode. You can query supported graphics modes via VESA functions.

Comment: An intro about VESA video modes can be found at [OSDev.org](https://wiki.osdev.org/Vesa).

Comment: The edited code now switches to mode 13h which is defined to be 320x200.